# This interaction failed even with await interaction.respond - discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a command that uses discord dropdown menus or select lists. It used to work completely fine, but for some reason it now starts to say 'This interaction failed'. I know I need to use reaction.response, but for some reason it doesnt work. Yesterday, it worked perfectly fine, and there wasnt anything that I changed really. But now for some reason whenever I choose something, it immediately says 'this interaction failed'. The only thing I changed was that I was solving out how to get the active dev badge, and im currently waiting for it. Other than that, I didnt change ANYTHING at all. This is my code:

```
if message.content.startswith('c!help'):
        select = Select(placeholder="Choose a category",
                        options=[
                            discord.SelectOption(label="Fun commands",
                                                 default=False),
                            discord.SelectOption(label="General commands",
                                                 default=False),
                            discord.SelectOption(label="Seasonal commands",default=False)
                        ])
        view = View()
        view.add_item(select)
        await message.channel.send(embed=fhelp, view=view)

        async def call_back(interaction):
            mainthing = select.values[0]
            if mainthing == "Fun commands":
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=fhelp, view=view)
            elif mainthing == "General commands":
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=ghelp, view=view)
            elif mainthing == "Seasonal commands":
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=shelp,view=view)

        select.callback = call_back
```

I made everything clear, and please dont avoid the main question. It worked completely fine.  I doubt there is a problem with my code since I didnt even change anything in it, but it just suddenly started saying that error in an instant. I believe its probably a bug or something related with the active dev badge thing.

Comment: You maybe have a typo here? It is not called `call_back`, rather `callback`

Comment: I changed it and it still doesnt work

Comment: Also, like I said, it used to work even with the same code. It just for some reason started not working.

Comment: Use `print` statements to see where it gets stuck

Comment: It gets stuck inside of the function. I put it above mainthing = select.values[0] and it doesnt print anything, and not inside of the if statements. I also tested it by creating a new bot and a new python sheet and it still doesnt work.